# get previous 12 month from sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, innodb

I have created Query which gets me the previous 12-month data which contain current month. I want the 12 months from the previous month. I don't get that, so can anyone help me over this.

```
create_data >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 12 month)
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (date_sub and curdate are product specific functions.)

Comment: you can  instead of using CURDATE() , use CURDATE()-30

Comment: @jarlh i am using InnoDB. (sql phpMyAdmin).

Comment: @Rome I don't think this work for me what if any month have 31 days or 29 ?

Comment: @ankitsuthar use DATE_SUB inside of function too 
DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) , INTERVAL 12 month)

Comment: @Rome No sir, I have tried your suggestion but that still gives me the current month in the previous month list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the 12 months up to last month:

```
create data between DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 13 month)
                and DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 month)
```

Comment: thanks, @JohnHC .  It looks like I get the previous 12 months. Just a Curiosity we get it without the between.  & yes, thanks for the help sir.

Comment: That is not aligned with a month boundary; perhaps you want that?

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE create_date >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL DAY(CURDATE() -1) DAY
                               - INTERVAL 12 MONTH
  AND create_date  < CURDATE() - INTERVAL DAY(CURDATE() -1) DAY
```

Backing up by `DAY(CURDATE())` gets to the end of the previous month.

The `-1` is to shift that to the first of the month.

`- INTERVAL 12 MONTH` gets back 12 months.

The use of `>=` and `<` prevents getting an extra day or second on the end.

To check:

```
SELECT NOW(),
   CURDATE() - INTERVAL DAY(CURDATE() -1) DAY
             - INTERVAL 12 MONTH  AS start,
   CURDATE() - INTERVAL DAY(CURDATE() -1) DAY

+---------------------+------------+------------+
| NOW()               | start      | end        |
+---------------------+------------+------------+
| 2017-02-27 15:31:09 | 2016-02-01 | 2017-02-01 |
+---------------------+------------+------------+
```

Comment: Thanks, Sir, I Wil try this and get back with the result. Thanks for your help.